# nested recyclerview to open a new activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I am new to Android developing and I am stuck and can't find solution how can I do `onClick()` event to open new activity for nested `RecyclerView`

this is `MainActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.recyclerviewmultitypeexample

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)





        var dataList = ArrayList<Data>()
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_SEVEN, "","","","","","","","február 28 - marec 06"," ",""))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_THREE, "Novinka na webstránke: ","Aktualizovaný","školský semafor - po jarných prázdninách","","" ,"","","Pia 04. mar","09:53",""))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_FOUR, "Bronislava Fačkovcová → Rodičia:","","Vážení rodičia,zasielam Vám Aktualizovaný školský semafor - platný po jarných prázdninách Do domácej izolácie ide iba žiak s pozitívnym...","","","","","","09:16 "," • lajkov: 19"))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_SEVEN, "","","","","","","","február 21 - 27"," ",""))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_TWO, "DÚ • ","Matematika"," • DÚ na jarné","prázdniny - PZ str 72 až 86","prehrať online"," • do: Piatok 07.03","","Sob 26. feb","09:51",""))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_FOUR, "Marcela Hanková → Rodičia:","Dobrý","deň, deto dostaváli tento týždeň šeky, poprosila by som vás o uhradenie v priebehu budúceho týždňa. Ak by ste mali nejasnosti, kľudne sa na mňa...","","","","","Štv 24. feb","12:40 "," • lajkov: 13"))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_FOUR, "Bronislava Fačkovcová → Rodičia:","","Vážení rodičia, oznamujeme Vám, že výdaj AG testov pre Vaše deti bude realizovaný v dňoch: 24.2.2022 od 13,30 do 16,30 hod 25.2.2022 od 06,03....","","","","","","12:34 ","lajkov: 27"))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_TWO, "DÚ • ","Dejepis"," • Veľmoci proti Hitlerovi","","prehrať online"," • do: Piatok 25.02","","Str 23. feb","13:26",""))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_SEVEN, "","","","","","","","február 14 - 20"," ",""))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_TWO, "DÚ • ","Anglický jazyk"," • Posielam nové ","učivo - verbs and nouns z dnešnej hodiny /18.2./. Opravná písomka z trpného rodu a zo slovíčok bude vo štvrtok 24.2.","prehrať online"," • do: Piatok 25.02","","Pia 18. feb","15:59",""))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_FOUR, "Bronislava Fačkovcová → 9.B + 10:","Milí","žiaci, oznamujem Vám, že narúšanie on - line hodín a zneužívanie identity iného žiaka je hrubým porušením školského poriadku. Vedenie školy rieši narúšanie...","","","","","","14:08 "," • lajkov: 19"))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_FOUR, "Silvia Habánová → 9.B • Slovenský jazyk a literatúra:","","Milí deviataci, hodina literatúry bude,ale z vážnych dôvodov sa možem pripojiť až okolo 11. Prosím, od 10.50 buďte už pripojení a robte...","","","","","","07:41 "," • lajkov: 1"))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_FOUR, "Gabriela Kašáková → Rodičia 9.B + 6:",""," Dobrý deň, dovoľte mi informovať Vás, že prihlášky na štúdium na SŠ pre všetkých žiakov 9.ročníka su vytlačené a pripravené na podpis zákonnými...","","","","","Štv 17. feb","19:26 "," • lajkov: 4"))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_TWO, "DÚ • ","Matematika"," • Ihlan - materiál na","hodinu"," prehrať online"," • do: Piatok 18.02","","","13:46",""))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_TWO, "DÚ • ","Matematika"," • Kužeľ - príklady 15 a","16"," prehrať online"," • do: Štvrtok 17.02","","","10:30",""))
        dataList.add(Data(RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_THREE, "Novinka na webstránke: ","Okresné kolo","Dejepisnej olympiády","","" ,"","","Str 16. feb","18:31"," • lajkov: 2"))





        val adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(this, dataList)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        System.out.println("hovno")




    }
}
```

this is `RecyclerViewAdapter.kt`

```
package com.example.recyclerviewmultitypeexample

import android.content.ClipData.Item
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class RecyclerViewAdapter(context: Context, list: ArrayList<Data>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {



    companion object {
        const val VIEW_TYPE_ONE = 1
        const val VIEW_TYPE_TWO = 2
        const val VIEW_TYPE_THREE = 3
        const val VIEW_TYPE_FOUR = 4
        const val VIEW_TYPE_FIVE = 5
        const val VIEW_TYPE_SIX = 6
        const val VIEW_TYPE_SEVEN = 7



    }




    private val context: Context = context
    var list: ArrayList<Data> = list

    private inner class View1ViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var message: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        var messages: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        var messagess: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4)
        var messagesss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)
        var messagessss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatum)



        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
            message.text = recyclerViewModel.textData
            messages.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu1
            messagess.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu2
            messagesss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu3
            messages.text = recyclerViewModel.textCas
            messagessss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDatum

        }
    }

    private inner class View2ViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var message: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        var messages: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        var messagess: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)
        var messagesss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3)
        var messagesssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPrehrat)
        var messagessssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5)
        var messagesssssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTime)
        var messagessss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatum)

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
            message.text = recyclerViewModel.textData
            messages.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu1
            messagess.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu2
            messagesss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu3
            messagesssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu4
            messagessssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu5
            messagesssssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textCas
            messagessss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDatum
        }
    }

    private inner class View3ViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var message: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        var messages: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        var messagess: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)
        var messagesssssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTime)
        var messagessss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatum)

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
            message.text = recyclerViewModel.textData
            messages.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu1
            messagess.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu2
            messagesssssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textCas
            messagessss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDatum

        }
    }

    private inner class View4ViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var message: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        var messages: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        var messagess: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)
        var messagesssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textLike)
        var messagesssssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTime)
        var messagessss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatum)

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
            message.text = recyclerViewModel.textData
            messages.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu1
            messagess.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu2
            messagesssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textLike
            messagessss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDatum
            messagesssssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textCas


        }
    }

    private inner class View5ViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var message: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        var messages: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)
        var messagess: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        var messagesssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4)
        var messagesssssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTime)
        var messagessss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatum)

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
            message.text = recyclerViewModel.textData
            messages.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu1
            messagess.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu2
            messagesssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu3
            messagesssssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textCas
            messagessss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDatum



        }
    }

    private inner class View6ViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var message: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        var messages: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        var messagesssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4)
        var messagessssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5)
        var messagesssssss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTime)
        var messagessss: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatum)

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
            message.text = recyclerViewModel.textData
            messages.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu1
            messagesssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu2
            messagessssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDu3
            messagesssssss.text = recyclerViewModel.textCas
            messagessss.text = recyclerViewModel.textDatum



        }
    }


    private inner class View7ViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var message: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatum)


        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
            message.text = recyclerViewModel.textDatum


        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ONE) {
            return View1ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_chybanie, parent, false)
            )
        }
        else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_TWO){
            return View2ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_du, parent, false)
            )
        }
        else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_THREE){
            return View3ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_news, parent, false)
            )
        }
        else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_FOUR){
            return View4ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_sprava, parent, false)
            )
        }
        else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_FIVE){
            return View5ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_suplovanie, parent, false)
            )
        }
        else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_SEVEN){
            return View7ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_datum, parent, false)
            )
        }
        return View6ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_znamka, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (list[position].viewType === VIEW_TYPE_ONE) {
            (holder as View1ViewHolder).bind(position)
        }
        else if(list[position].viewType === VIEW_TYPE_TWO){
            (holder as View2ViewHolder).bind(position)
        }
        else if(list[position].viewType === VIEW_TYPE_THREE){
            (holder as View3ViewHolder).bind(position)
        }
        else if(list[position].viewType === VIEW_TYPE_FOUR){
            (holder as View4ViewHolder).bind(position)
        }
        else if(list[position].viewType === VIEW_TYPE_FIVE){
            (holder as View5ViewHolder).bind(position)
        }
        else if(list[position].viewType === VIEW_TYPE_SEVEN){
            (holder as View7ViewHolder).bind(position)
        }

        else {
            (holder as View6ViewHolder).bind(position)
        }


    }




    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return list[position].viewType
    }


}
```

this is `Data.kt`

```
package com.example.recyclerviewmultitypeexample

data class Data(val viewType: Int, val textData: String,val textDu1 : String,val textDu2 : String,val textDu3 : String,val textDu4 : String,val textDu5 : String,val textDu6 : String,val textDatum : String,val textCas : String,val textLike : String)
```